# String to syntax Python

Tags: python, string, syntax, config, configparser

I use `configparser` to get values for my python script, but I need to call function stored in `config.ini`... Since all values in configparser are stored as strings, is it possible to transform string into syntax? If so, how?

Comment: You can `exec` the string, or I suppose `eval` if it is a `lambda` expression ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `eval`, documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

Or you can try `exec`, documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/exec.html).

By be careful, these are just quick and dirty way.

A better and much more safer method is to use `getattr()` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)) and `setattr()` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)) which indexes into `globals`.

Comment: @Mirac7: `ast.literal_eval` is the safe way. It won't handle actual Python expressions like `'a' + 'b'`, but it will transform literal strings like `[1, 2]` and `{'a': 'b'}` into Python objects. `eval()` is easily exploitable.